# How to convert varchar to a date in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, str-to-date

I have in my database a date `fetcha_pago` in the format: "08-Abr-2016" and it is a varchar. When I do the following:

```
STR_TO_DATE(fecha_pago, '%d-%M-%Y')
```

It does not work because the date is in Spanish. It has to be "Apr" instead of "Abr". Is there a way to respect "Abr" for the month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing dates as strings causes all sorts of problems and locale is one of them. If you can convert these to [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column.

Date formatting should be done in PHP and only when you know the locale you're rendering into. Anything in the database should be stored in a neutral format. String dates are borderline useless, they can't be sorted or indexed.

You'll probably have to chain twelve `REPLACE()` statements together to re-write each month name:

```
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(REPLACE(fetcha_pago, 'Ene', 'Jan'), 'Abr', 'Apr'), '%d-%M-%Y')
```

That's just two levels, but you can expand to cover all those that are different.

Comment: This solution works form me : STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(REPLACE(fetcha_pago, 'Ene', 'Jan'), 'Abr', 'Apr'), '%d-%M-%Y'), But do i need to replace all the months ? or just the ones that change??

Comment: Just the ones that change. If there are some that are coincidentally the same you can skip those. The expanded version is pretty huge, so I left that out, but just repeat that pattern.

Comment: Thank you. You help me a lot =)